# Django context processors argument error

Tags: python, django

I'm showing all customers list with django render to response method like this.

my url

```
url(r'^view/(?P<uuid>\w+)/$', views.customer, name="customer"),
```

My view

```
def customer(request,uuid):
    current_customer = Customers.objects.filter(uuid=uuid)
    return render_to_response('customers/customer.html',{'current_customer':current_customer},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my template

```
{% for customer in current_customer %}
    <h2 class="title">Customer - {{customer.name}}</h2>
{%empty %}
    <h2 class="title">Customer not found </h2>
{% endfor %}
```

This method working fine. But, when I change to context processors method, I got error. I'm included this context to my settings.py.

my context_processors.py

```
def customer(request,uuid):
    current_customer = Customers.objects.filter(uuid=uuid)

    return {
        'current_customer': current_customer
    }
```

my view

```
def customer(request,uuid):
    return render_to_response('customers/customer.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

error is `customer() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`.
if I remove `request` from argument error gone. but result `customer not found`. What is missing in my code.

Comment: context_processor only takes 1 argument:request

Comment: @Leonardo.Z so, I can't use this method via context processors. right?

Comment: You can still use context_processors. You just need to store the uuid into the request object in your views and read the uuid from the request object in your context_processors

Comment: @Leonardo.Z which is a complete misuse of context processors. If something depends on the view, it shouldn't be in a context processor.